# Why @JavaConfig not working in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I'm trying to setup Spring MVC project without dispatcher xml and web xml(i.e. without any xml at all). Hence, I'm using @JavaConfig technique of Spring. However, whenever I'm trying to start the application on my server my server it's not working(without throwing any exception it's getting HTTP 404).
Here is the snapshot of the project structure...
[image]

And here the code snippets:
**WebConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String VIEW_LOCATION = "/WEB-INF/views/";
    private static final String SUFFIX = ".jsp";

//  @Override
//  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
//      System.out.println("in resource");
//      registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");       
//  }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        System.out.println("in view");
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix(VIEW_LOCATION);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(SUFFIX);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

**Initializer.java**

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/";

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("in config");
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        System.out.println("dispatcher");
        return new String[] { MAPPING_URL };
    }

}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome() {
        System.out.println("in servlet");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

And here is the pox.xml snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>UI</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>UI Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>UI</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What's the url you are trying?

Comment: Just http://localhost:8080/

Comment: What kind of app server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project structure looks good but I doubt about the Eclipse configuration. Looks like your package is not being a part of Java Source.

Please execute the following steps:

**1.** Verify `Source` set for project. Go to project properties, `Java Build Path` and on `Source` tab, look for the entries `src\main\java` and `src\main\resources`. If not present, click on `Add Folder` to add source folders and it should similar to the below:

[image: Source Folders]

**2.** Go to `Deployment Assembly` and verify that the you have deployment entry mappings in the right way. If you do not find `Deployment Assembly`, go to `Project Facets` and go for the option to convert the project to faceted form. In `Project Facets`, you should have `Dynamic Web Module` selected.

`Deployment Assembly` should have mappings from `Maven Dependencies` to `WEB-INF/lib`, `/src/main/webapp` to `/`, `src/main/resources` to `WEB-INF/classes` and `src/main/java` to `WEB-INF/classes`. If any of these entries are missing, you may click `Add` and choose `Folder` or `Libraries` as required.

[image: Deployment Descriptor]

**3.** Make sure that you access the project using the `Context Root` name mentioned in the `Web Project Settings` of your project, if you are deploying the application through Eclipse and not through maven or some other tool.

[image: Web Project Settings]

In the above case, you can access the application by `localhost:8080/UI` where the server port `8080` may vary according to configuration.

Comment: @Abhinabyte, glad to know. Happy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all right. I was execute them without any changes on `Tomcat 8` application server.
Use Maven to package `war`, `mvn clean package`.