# Spring mvc - org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There are a lot of similar questions asked on net but none solved my problem.I want to make simple 'hello world' app using spring mvc annotations based approach but stuck on this error for 1 week now.

The error which I get when I hit http://localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/welcome on the browser is 404, the requested resource is not available and console display's the following:

```
 Nov 12, 2015 11:56:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCProject/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />

 <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
 </bean>


  </beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.gontuseries.hellocontroller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        model.addObject("msg","hello world");

        return model;
    }

}
```

**HelloPage.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>First Spring MVC Application Demo</h1>

    <h2>${msg}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

**I am using spring mvc 4.2 and Apache tomcat 7.0**

P.S. **Everything was working fine when I was using the non annotations based approach, I was able to see the running web page, until I went for the annotations based approach.**

EDIT: Screenshot of my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you do '@RequestMapping(value="/welcome")

Comment: @James Jithin Yes using Eclipse.

Comment: @bmarkham same result

Comment: Try this '@RequestMapping(value= {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)'. If THAT doesn't work, import your web server in eclipse, right like your project, select 'Run as...', then 'Run on server'

Comment: try removing <mvc:annotation-driven/> from your config

Comment: I doubt about the deployment assembly. Please do as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32931296/584420

Answer (score 0):

check you tomcat config file,did you project name are:FirstSpringMVCProject,you can try visit http://localhost:8080/welcome

Answer (score 0):

By default spring project take the last part of your base package name as project name and add it to your pom.xml as artifactId tag  so please try to hit this url

**http://localhost:8080/hellocontroller/welcome**

Comment: I don't have any pom.xml as I am not using any automation tool like maven or gradle, just using basic set up.

Comment: just gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

"dispacher-servlet.xml" seems to be mis-spelt i.e., it ought to be "dispatcher-servlet.xml".
It ought to match the servlet name that you have defined in web.xml

Comment: Thanks, was mis-spelled while writing the question, it's correct in my development environment...updated now!!

Comment: Can you share your project structure?

Comment: Screenshot of my directory structure updated in question, plz check.

Answer (score 0):

try the following solution:

1.double click on the server in eclipse  there you have modules click the modules tab there will  be a path mentioned change it to FirstSpringMvcProject

2.go to the properties tab by pressing alt+enter in eclipse there you have web project settings change the path to FirstSpringMvcProject

3. go to http://localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/welcome there you will have you first mvc spring app