# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found for AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to initialise my web application using `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` as opposed to a web.xml file. I've extended this class in my own `MySocialNetworkWebAppInitializer` class:

```
public class MySocialNetworkWebAppInitializer
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

I've implemented a controller `HomeController` to listen for requests at "/". When I run the application I get the following:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found ... The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

When I created the project there was a web.xml file by default, which I've removed as I want to use `MySocialNetworkWebAppInitializer`. What am I missing in order to run the application using this new initializer?

My project set up is shown below:

[image]

My `HomeController.java`:

```
package com.petehallw.mysocialnetwork.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

My `WebConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.petehallw.mysocialnetwork.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my project structure? How do I make it aware of my initializer?

I have noticed references to 'web.xml' in my server. How do I point it to my initialiser instead?

[image]

Comment: How do you run or deploy the application? You might need to do additional configuration on the server to change the context path.

Comment: @bahti I am running it from Eclipse using a Tomcat v8.5 server at localhost. How do I change the configuration to not look at the web.xml but my initialiser? I've added a screenshot to show the references.

Comment: Do you use maven's pom for managing dependency ? If yes can you add that to post. Do you use maven's war plugin for generating war ? Also, was the project working before with web.xml ? Can you verify your deployed war doesn't have web.xml ? Is your dynamic web module facet set to 3.0 ? You can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930281/why-javaconfig-not-working-in-spring-mvc to verify your eclipse configuration.

Comment: @Veeram Thank you for that link! After adding Maven Dependencies to the Deployment Assembly, it's now running OK! Please add an answer and I'll give you credit.